# How do I fill a 2D array with consecutively decreasing numbers from a central point

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a 2D array with a "light source" placed at a coordinate on it. This light source has a brightness value attached to it. I was wondering how I would make it such that this light illuminated the tiles around it to a distance equal to its brightness, with each illuminated tiles brightness equal to its distance from the source. For example a bulb with brightness 5 would illuminate with a radius of 5 cells, with cells 2 steps away having a brightness of 4 and those 5 steps away with 1.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [questions asking for "homework" help must include a summary of the work done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty solving it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you set a value in a 2D array?

```
final int SIZE = 30; // size of array
int[][] brightnessOfTiles = new int[SIZE][SIZE];

brightnessOfTiles[x][y] = 1234; // some value
```

How do you determine value of the light at a specific place?

```
int centerX = 15; // x coordinate of position of light source
int centerY = 10; // y coordinate of position of light source
float dropoffFactor = 1; // how fast the brightness fades
brightnessOfTiles[x][y] = MAX_BRIGHTNESS / (1 + dropoffFactor * getDistanceSquaredBetweenPoints(x, y, centerX, centerY));
```

How do you determine the distance between two points?

```
private int getDistanceSquaredBetweenPoints(x, y, centerX, centerY){

    // formula is: distance = sqrt( (x - cx) ^ 2 + (y - cy) ^ 2 )
    //   so, distance ^ 2 = (x - cx) ^ 2 + (y - cy) ^ 2

    return Math.pow(centerX - x, 2) + Math.pow(centerY - y, 2);
}
```

How would you iterate over a 2D array?

```
for(int x = 0; x < SIZE; x++){
    for(int y = 0; y < SIZE; y++){

        brightnessOfTiles[x][y] = ...; // see above
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not being specific with what previous things I have tried. This isn't homework by the way, just a personal project. I'm trying to get more familiar with Java after working in Matlab for ages. I suppose a better question would have been about the distance between two of the points, which you helped me with. So thank you very much.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please also upvote the answer.

Comment: I don't have a high enough reputation to I'm afraid. When I do I shall come back and do so.